# How to implement the correct ReadLine() using System.IO.Pipelines and SequenceReader

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.pipelines

How to implement the correct ReadLine() using System.IO.Pipelines and SequenceReader

I have implemented ReadLine() in C# using Pipe and SequenceReader.
The result of ReadLine() is not handled correctly when the PipeReader input is fragmented.

## File details

```csharp
using System.Buffers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Text;

internal class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var pipe = new Pipe();
        var writer = pipe.Writer;
        var reader = pipe.Reader;

        var index = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            // Fragment simulation
            if (index < Data.Length)
            {
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data[index]);
                await writer.WriteAsync(data);
                writer.Advance(data.Length);
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                await pipe.Writer.CompleteAsync();
            }

            // Read
            var result = await reader.ReadAsync();
            var buffer = result.Buffer;

            while (ReadLine(ref buffer) is { } str)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(str);
            }

            // ?
            reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

            if (result.IsCompleted || result.IsCanceled)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        await reader.CompleteAsync();
    }

    private static string? ReadLine(ref ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer)
    {
        var reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(buffer);
        if (reader.TryReadTo(out ReadOnlySpan<byte> line, "\r\n"u8))
        {
            buffer = buffer.Slice(reader.Position);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(line);
        }

        return default;
    }

    private static readonly string[] Data =
    {
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc\r\n",
        "xxx",
        "\r\n",
        "yyy",
        "\r",
        "\n"
    };
}
```

## Expected result

```
"aaabbbccc"
"xxx"
"yyy"
```

## Actual result

```
"aaa\0\0\0bbb\0\0\0ccc"
"\0\0\0\0\0xxx\0\0\0"
```

## Questions

I think I am using PipeReader.AdvanceTo() incorrectly, what would be the correct description?
Note that until a newline is found, we want the buffer to be managed in the PipeReader.
I do not want an answer that uses StringBuilder to process up to the part that has been read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WriteAsync` method will automatically advance the write position. The `Advance` method is used when using other methods to write data.

```
await writer.WriteAsync(data);
//writer.Advance(data.Length);
```

For example this is an equivalent method to `WriteAsync` but using `Advance`:

```
data.AsSpan().CopyTo(writer.GetSpan(data.Length));
writer.Advance(data.Length);
await writer.FlushAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var pipe = new Pipe();
        var writer = pipe.Writer;
        var reader = pipe.Reader;

        var index = 0;
        var concatenatedLine = new StringBuilder();

        while (true)
        {
            if (index < Data.Length)
            {
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data[index]);
                await writer.WriteAsync(data);
                writer.Advance(data.Length);
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                await pipe.Writer.CompleteAsync();
            }
            var result = await reader.ReadAsync();
            var buffer = result.Buffer;

            string? line;
            while ((line = ReadLine(ref buffer)) is { })
            {
                concatenatedLine.Append(line);
            }

            if (line == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(concatenatedLine.ToString());
                concatenatedLine.Clear();
            }
            reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

            if (result.IsCompleted || result.IsCanceled)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        await reader.CompleteAsync();
    }

    private static string? ReadLine(ref ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer)
    {
        var reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(buffer);

        while (!reader.End)
        {
            if (reader.TryReadTo(out ReadOnlySpan<byte> line, (byte)'\n'))
            {
                buffer = buffer.Slice(reader.Position);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(line);
            }

            reader.Advance(buffer.Length);
        }

        return default;
    }

    private static readonly string[] Data =
    {
        "aaa",
        "bbb",
        "ccc\r\n",
        "xxx",
        "\r\n",
        "yyy",
        "\r",
        "\n"
    };
}
```